# Two Drop down options binding based on ID knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I have the following:

```
     <select data-bind="options: animals, value: optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name'" />

        self.animals = ko.mapping.fromJS([
            {"Name": "Tamed": , "ID": "1" },
            {"Name": "Wild": , "ID": "2" },
            ]);

        self.wildOrTamed = ko.mapping.fromJS([
            { "Name": "Cat", "ID": "1" },
            { "Name": "Lion", "ID": "2" },
            { "Name": "Cat": "1"  },
            { "Name": "Tiger", "ID": "2"  }]);
```

What I want this to have 2 drop down one for animals to select either Tamed or Wild and then based on that change my wildOrTamed drop down to show either wild animals or Tamed animals using the specified ID.

Note: this is dynamic so there could be other types of animals...

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why does wildOrTamed repeat "Cat"?

Comment: Oh, I meant to say Name as my optionsText is Name. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/6w4N8/

```
<select data-bind="options: animalTypes, value: animalType, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
<select data-bind="options: animalsForType, value: selectedAnimal, optionsValue: 'ID', optionsText: 'Name'"></select>

self.animalTypes = ko.observable([{"Name": "Tamed","ID": "1"},
    {"Name": "Wild","ID": "2"},
    {"Name": "Something else","ID": "3"}]);

self.animals = [{"Name": "Cat","ID": "1"},
    {"Name": "Lion","ID": "2"},
    {"Name": "Cat","ID": "1"}, 
    {"Name": "Tiger","ID": "2"}];
self.animalType = ko.observable();
self.selectedAnimal = ko.observable();
self.animalsForType = ko.computed(function () {
    var selectedType = self.animalType();
    return !selectedType ? [] : self.animals.filter(function (animal) {
        return animal.ID == selectedType;
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This did help, I was looking for this solution. I was in the right path, but didn't know about the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not 100% sure but following link will help you creating cascading drop down.
http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/06/cascading-dropdown-knockoutjs-aspnet.html

Comment: I guess I am looking for an option to simply do it with Knockout instead of going back to my Controller.